# teams adaptive cards with jpg image

Tags: node.js, image, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I send adaptive card to teams.

When I use png image it works fine, when I use jpg the image is not displayed properly in teams:

[image]

Below is the code (I created it using https://adaptivecards.io/designer/, and the image does show up correctly there):

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Image",
            "url": "https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG#/media/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5:PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "someText",
                    "data": {
                        "text": "someText"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**What is the problem?**

Comment: Are both of the images from wikipedia?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow. 
Actually my pictures from S3, but when I saw that there was a problem I tried Wikipedia images, and there I saw that png works and jpg did not.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for clarifying - I've had issues with wikipedia because it does some redirection on the images.

Comment: Hey, it must be some problem with the image source. Maybe it requires authentication behind S3 or multiple redirects. I just tried a random jpg from google and it worked. You can even use binary images instead of image urls. Usually thats no problem. Best bet is try to open the image in an icognito tab directly, only if that works it can work in teams. Not guaranted tho.

Comment: MS Teams normally doesn't have any problems rendering images from either binary data or url's. What is causing issues often are either multiple redirects, or authentication.

Comment: But when I use png from S3 (same navigation) it works

Comment: @HodayaShalom, Try keeping the jpg in local and see if it works. Once check it in Dec tool if that is getting accessed properly from S3.

Comment: @HodayaShalom - Did you try Abhijit's suggestion? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @HodayaShalom - Are you still working on this?